# How to deal with possible errors that arise from dereferencing a nullptr?

Tags: c++, exception, nullptr

I have a question regarding some guidelines to write better code. Suppose that I have a class like this:

```
class A {
private:
    T *m_data;
public: 
    A(T *data) : m_data(data) {}
    
    void doSomething() {
        //accessing m_data
    } 
};
```

Since it's possible to call A constructor passing a nullptr, what is the correct way to handle this problem in optic to be helpful to someone who want to re-use my code ?
A comment with a precondition is enough ?

```
//precondition : m_data != nullptr
void doSomething() {
        //accessing m_data
    }
```

Or is it better to check if `m_data==nullptr` and throw an exception with an error message giving the possibility to handle it or to let the program abort?

Comment: It would be better to use smart pointers vs raw pointers

Comment: Not acceptance of `nullptr` is usually self-documented by using references `A::A(T& data) : m_data(&data) {}`.

Comment: @paisanco — that doesn’t address the null pointer issue.

Comment: It very much depends on what you want the behaviour of the class to be. Should it not allow for null being stored in `m_data`? Consider using a reference or, assuming you need a copyable/movable class at least make the constructor parameter a reference. If a null value is a valid state, you need to decide on the desired effects of the function being called. An exception can be a desireable way of dealing with this as well as simply ignoring the function call or using default values. The `assert` macro can be useful for detecting function calls in an invalid state early btw.

Comment: @Pete Becker True, OP still needs to instantiate the smart pointer somehow

Comment: `A(T *data) : m_data(data) { if(!m_data} throw std::std::runtime_error("don't pass me a null ptr");  }`

Comment: If you can use `gsl`,  you may accept `gsl::not_null<T*>`. It's also a simple enough utility to implement in your own code base, so the guideline support  library isn't strictly required. Other schools of thought suggest simply adding an `assert`, since it's a pre-condition of your class (asserts serve such a purpose well).

Comment: Then there's those who think references solve this. But IMO, that's misguided. A non const lvalue reference is a bug waiting to happen. Non-explicit mutabillity on the part of the caller should be avoided.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I would say `T && data` would be the right thing then because then it's explicit that the caller gives up ownership.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow - And who said giving up ownership is correct? Non owning handles are a *must* in any language. mutability != ownership.

Comment: You are right, I assumed the `A` would take over ownership. But the lack of `~A()` means it doesn't (or leaks memory). That means a `std::shared_ptr<gsl::not_null<T*>>` sounds like the right thing if you change m,_data too. Or change the class to have `std::unique_ptr<T> m_data;` or a `~A()`.

Comment: The best way to deal with possible errors from dereferencing a null pointer is to not dereference a null pointer. A null pointer dereference causes undefined behaviour, so there is no consistent way to detect, let alone "deal with", such things.

Comment: @273K it's poor style for a function to save the address of an argument passed by reference though.  The reference parameter implies to the caller that that won't happen .

Comment: @M.M Why do you talk this to me? I don't save addresses of arguments.

Comment: @273K You suggested `A::A(T& data) : m_data(&data)`, which saves the address of argument `data`

Comment: @M.M Aaaahhhh. It was just for making it syntactically correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is always: there is no single correct way, or rule that always applies.

For example, suppose your class is the start of a custom iterator definition. Dereferencing default-constructed or end() iterators is usually undefined behaviour, even if they don't represent null values. The non-default constructor could be similar to yours, but since users aren't supposed to call it directly and the behaviour is documented, that's not really a problem. But still, the iterator simply assumes that it's in a valid state and will let you violate these rules. It provides a default constructor (and would therefore avoid having reference members) just to be "[regular](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/regular)", which is a convenient and intuitive property.

So in that case, it doesn't really matter whether the constructor accepts a pointer or a reference, as long as the class does not do anything surprising with the referenced object, such as destroying it. However, your case may be different and so your design may end up being different. In general your code should be unsurprising and self-documenting as much as possible. What is surprising is of course subjective, but I personally find a class that is not (semi)regular more surprising than one whose default-constructed state is invalid in some sense. You could look at resources like the [ISO C++ guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines), especially [interfaces](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#S-interfaces) and [functions](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#S-functions) for many well-documented examples, both good and bad ones!